# I'm unable to find keytool while working on android environment?

Tags: java, android, keytool

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NJ7er.png)

Hello everyone,
I'm not able to find the keytool key while working on the android enviroment, I have tried usindg command prompts debug.keystore but there are no files of keytool.Kindly help me out here.

Comment: Hi,

Keytool is basically part of JDK. Please check your JDK you will got the keytool.

Comment: Hi Amit , I got it finally , had the updated JDK version in a different folder, hence was unable to locate it.

Answer (score 0):

You will find it in C:\Program Files\Java\jdkXXXX\bin\keytool.exe.

Answer (score 0):

you can find keytool.exe in below path
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\bin

Answer (score 0):

thank you for your comments, I got the keytool path, also ,since I'm using windows based system, I had to further use 
keytool -list -v -keystore "%USERPROFILE%.android\debug.keystore" -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android

to get appropriate answer .